# How to retrieve a value string of JSON and implode it in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I need to retrieve the "data" value of my JSON and implode it.

**MySQL** ('wave' column)

```
{"sample_rate":44100,"samples_per_pixel":4410,"bits":8,"length":2668,"data":[0.13,0.19,0.15,0.11,0.13,0.13,0.24,0.35]}
```

So I tried:

**PHP**

```
$json = $row['wave'];
$json_array = json_decode($json);
$json_wave = implode(',', $json_array->data);
```

But I got this warning:

```
Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ...
```

How can I implode the data value without encounter in that warning?

Comment: Its working: [Eval](http://smal.me.pn/dW4). @u_mulder Check this [Eval](http://smal.me.pn/fj9) will get error when used as array, OP uses object array not an array

Comment: @Thamilan indeed my example is working correctly, but I get that warning message from PHP debug.